# PulseAudio cannot see working USB sound card

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, alsa, pulseaudio

I have a Raspberry Pi, running Raspbian, with a cheap SoundBlaster USB card plugged into it. The card is visible to ALSA:

```
# aplay -l | grep card
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 2: bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI1 [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI1]
card 1: S3 [Sound Blaster Play! 3], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
```

And I can play sound through this card:

`$ speaker-test -Dhw:1,0 -c2 -twav`

does output "front left" and "front right" in a woman's voice through the connected speakers.

However, PulseAudio does not recognize the card:

```
$ pacmd list-sinks|egrep -i 'index:|name:'
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
```

I'm not even sure how to select this card in `alsamixer`; hitting "F2" and looking at `/proc/asound/cards` does show this, but then "F6" only shows the default card and trying to enter another value, like "S3" (the name of the card) or "1" or "hw1" or "hw:1,0" just returns "Cannot open mixer device [whatever]. No such file or directory."

I've tried a variety of solutions I've found; none of them work. For example, adding `load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:1,0` to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` does not trigger an error, but it also does not change the output of `pacmd list-sinks`, and does not give me any sound.

Adding an ALSA configuration file consisting of:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

*does* make the USB card available to alsamixer, and I can then play things directly through ALSA, e.g. `$ aplay test.wav`, but it's still invisible to Pulse via `list-sinks`, and if I try to play anything through Pulse, I get errors or no sound, e.g. with `mocp sample.mp3` there's no sound.

I can't imagine this should be so hard, so I assume I'm missing something obvious. Could someone tell me what it is?

[EDIT:]

The output of `ls -l /dev/snd` is:

```
$ ls -l /dev/snd
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       60 Jan 12 17:01 by-id
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       80 Jan 12 17:01 by-path
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  0 Jan 12 17:01 controlC0
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116, 32 Jan 12 17:01 controlC1
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116, 16 Jan 12 17:01 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116, 17 Jan 12 17:01 pcmC0D1p
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116, 18 Jan 12 17:01 pcmC0D2p
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116, 56 Jan 12 17:01 pcmC1D0c
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116, 48 Jan 12 17:01 pcmC1D0p
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  1 Jan 12 17:01 seq
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116, 33 Jan 12 17:01 timer
```

Comment: Please show the output of `ls -l /dev/snd/`.

Comment: (Added into the original post; it was too long, and couldn't be formatted correctly, as a comment. Thanks.)

Comment: In theory, there should be no difference in the cards found by `aplay -l` and alsamixer's F6. Are you executing everything as root, or is your user member of the audio group?

Comment: The user is in the audio group, but that seems not to matter for the ALSA stuff. Both `aplay -l` and alsamixer's F6 will show nothing if executed as that user, but will show results if executed as root. But that doesn't seem to be the problem--again, I can play sound by using `aplay`. It's that Pulse doesn't see the other card. (I'm launching Pulse as the user, though I'll eventually switch to running it as a system daemon, despite the warnings against this.)

Comment: Are you using `aplay -D hw:1` or `aplay -D default`? The latter uses PulseAudio.

Comment: `aplay -D h1:1` (or `hw:1,0`) works when run as root, not otherwise. Hmm, `aplay -D default` shows that it's running, but there's no sound, as the user, but `aplay -D default` *does* produce sound when run as root! Um, what does this mean?

Comment: What are the rights on the directory itself (`ls -ld /dev/snd`)? Are there ACLs? What error message do you get with `cat /dev/snd/controlC1`?

Comment: Sorry for delay. Rights on ``/dev/snd` are `drwxr-xr-x 4 root root`. On `cat /dev/snd/controlC1`, I get a "Permission denied" as the user, "File descriptor in bad state" as root. Thanks for keeping going with this.

Comment: Hey! I'm not sure what I did, but I rebooted the Pi--I'd done this before--and now it's working.

Comment: FYI I see such behavior **sometimes** connecting a second sound card.